# jsonnet - output multiple files from seed array

Tags: jsonnet

Just getting started with *jsonnet*. My goal is to generate multiple json files from template json and seed array.

I've seen that you can use `for` syntax to iterate and also the the Multiple File Output section under the Getting Started but not how to make this work from a single json template https://jsonnet.org/learning/getting_started.html

Imagine the json template has `id` and `colours` as variable and perhaps other fields are static like `enabled`

```
{ 
  id: x.id, 
  colours: x.colours, 
  enabled: true 
}
```

and maybe the seed values - i'm not committed to this format, the following is more to give you example of data to be fed to the template to produce 2 files

```
{
  'basic.json': { id: 'basic', colours: ['white',black'] },
  'standard.json': { id: 'standard', colours: ['red','green'] },
}
```

goal output

```
$ jsonnet -m . multiple_output.jsonnet
basic.json
standard.json

$ cat basic.json 
{ 
  id: 'basic', 
  colours: ['white',black'], 
  enabled: true 
}

$ cat standard.json 
{ 
  id: 'standard', 
  colours: ['red','green'], 
  enabled: true 
}
```

Any direction of where to go with this would be great - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, below code should achieve what you need:

NOTE btw that your `basic.json` and `standard.json` expected output examples are not valid JSON, in particular the keys are not quoted.

### foo.json

```js
[
  { "id": "basic", "colours": ["white","black"] },
  { "id": "standard", "colours": ["red","green"] }
]
```

### foo.jsonnet

```jsonnet
local input = import 'foo.json';

local template = {
  id: error 'id is required',
  colours: [],
  enabled: true,
};

// Small wrapper function to make final comprehension more readable
local fileName(entry) = '%s.json' % entry.id;

// Create object keyed by `fileName(entry)`, with value
// as result of merging template and entry from input array
{ [fileName(entry)]: template + entry for entry in input }
```

### output

```bash
$ jsonnet -m . foo.jsonnet
./basic.json
./standard.json
$ cat basic.json
{
   "colours": [
      "white",
      "black"
   ],
   "enabled": true,
   "id": "basic"
}
$ cat standard.json
{
   "colours": [
      "red",
      "green"
   ],
   "enabled": true,
   "id": "standard"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Its just clicked that you manipulate the jsonnet file to become the format for multifile output.